# How hardware interrupt works on music

Tags: operating-systems

Does music stop for a short interval while listening into it,maybe a milliseconds that we just doesnt sense it cause by interrupts for operating system to run other programs

Comment: Modern systems use buffering and separate hardware for audio playback. See [this article](http://www.soundonsound.com/sos/apr99/articles/letency.htm) from 1999 (search in article for "small RAM buffers" for the most relevant paragraph). Or see [this article](http://0pointer.de/blog/projects/pulse-glitch-free.html)